# DSolveValue differential equation list of arbitrary values

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, matrix

I have been solving arrays of differential equations, and recently moved to the general case, where my initial conditions are arbitrary constants (either real or complex). However when I moved from using `NDSolveValue` to `DSolveValue` the output that is given is unclear to me. If anyone could help clear up my confusion that would be fantastic.

````
$Assumptions = {Subscript[b, 0] \[Element] Reals, 
   Subscript[a, 0] \[Element] Reals};

w1 = 1000000;

\[Tau] = \[Pi]/(w1);

mat = {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}};

H = Exp[-t^2/(2*\[Tau]^2)] * w1 * mat;

funcs = Array[p[#1, #2][t] &, {4, 4}];

equation = Flatten@Join[Thread[D[funcs, t] == I (funcs.H - H.funcs)]];

f = Table[
   DSolveValue[equation[[i, 1, k]] == equation[[i, 2, k]], 
    funcs[[i, k]], {t, -4*10^-6, 4*10^-6}], {k, 4}, {i, 4}] // MatrixForm
```
````

Answer (score 0):

An extended comment rather than an answer follows.

Reviewing your code after pasting it into a Mathematica notebook, raised some questions.

It does not appear that you have defined `t`.  Nothing wrong with this if you want your code to treat it as a symbol, but my reading of your code leaves your intention unclear.

Note: your use of the following, `D[funcs, t]` stands as something entirely different.

This raises more questions.

Do you actually want to define `funcs` as a function, e.g.,

`funcs[t] := Array[p[#1, #2][t] &, {4, 4}];`,

then recast `D[funcs, t]` as `D[funcs[t], t]`?

Doing so would address some issues of the undefined `t`, but then you still have `t` undefined in:

`H = Exp[-t^2/(2*\[Tau]^2)]*w1*mat;`

and within:

`DSolveValue[ equation[[i, 1, k]] == equation[[i, 2, k]], funcs[[i, k]], {t, -4*10^-6, 4*10^-6}]`

Also,

`funcs[t] := Array[p[#1, #2][t] &, {4, 4}]`

produces the following:

`{{p[1, 1][3 + (2 + (1 + x^2)^2)^2], p[1, 2][3 + (2 + (1 + x^2)^2)^2],  p[1, 3][3 + (2 + (1 + x^2)^2)^2],  p[1, 4][3 + (2 + (1 + x^2)^2)^2]}, {p[2, 1][ 3 + (2 + (1 + x^2)^2)^2], p[2, 2][3 + (2 + (1 + x^2)^2)^2],  p[2, 3][3 + (2 + (1 + x^2)^2)^2],  p[2, 4][3 + (2 + (1 + x^2)^2)^2]}, {p[3, 1][ 3 + (2 + (1 + x^2)^2)^2], p[3, 2][3 + (2 + (1 + x^2)^2)^2],  p[3, 3][3 + (2 + (1 + x^2)^2)^2],  p[3, 4][3 + (2 + (1 + x^2)^2)^2]}, {p[4, 1][ 3 + (2 + (1 + x^2)^2)^2], p[4, 2][3 + (2 + (1 + x^2)^2)^2],  p[4, 3][3 + (2 + (1 + x^2)^2)^2], p[4, 4][3 + (2 + (1 + x^2)^2)^2]}}`

Does this make sense for what you intend?

Finally, best practices in Mathematica avoid defining variables with capital letters.  Rather than `H = Exp[-t^2/(2*\[Tau]^2)]*w1*mat;` consider using. `h = Exp[-t^2/(2*\[Tau]^2)]*w1*mat;`

You may have perfectly sound reasons for everything on which I've commented.
I only offer the above in in hopes it may help you think through the code and identify issues.

Answer (score 0):

It seems DSolve can not solve some of the equations (at least my version 8.0). (Rescaled your w1 to 1)

```
$Assumptions = {Subscript[b, 0] \[Element] Reals, 
Subscript[a, 0] \[Element] Reals};
w1 = 1;
\[Tau] = \[Pi]/(w1);
mat = {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}};
(H = Exp[-t^2/(2*\[Tau]^2)]*w1*mat) // MatrixForm

funcs = Array[p[#1, #2][t] &, {4, 4}]

vars = Variables[Flatten[funcs][[All, 0]]]

vars3 = {p[2, 2], p[2, 3], p[3, 2], p[3, 3]};

equation = 
  Thread /@ Thread[D[funcs, t] == I (funcs.H - H.funcs)] // Flatten

dsol = DSolve[equation, vars, t]
```

Gives no solution. It has problems with equtions {6, 7, 10, 11}

```
eq2 = equation[[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}]]

dsol2 = DSolve[eq2, Complement[vars, vars3], t]

eq3 = equation[[{6, 7, 10, 11}]]

DSolve[eq3, vars3, t]
```